# epub parsing using epub.js

Tags: javascript, epub

I am using https://github.com/augustl/js-epub to parse an .epub file.but i got error as "XML parsing error :no element found".i am not having problem up to step 3,it fails in post processing step.I am using the following code

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#something').html('fetching');
    $.ajax({
    url: "alice.epub",
    complete: function(response, status, request) {
    var the_zip = new JSUnzip(response.responseText);
    $('#something').html('finished with ' + status);
    console.log("is it zip?" + the_zip.isZipFile());
    var epub = new JSEpub(response.responseText);
    epub.processInSteps(function (step, extras) {
    var msg = '';
    console.log(step);
    if (step === 1) {
    msg = "Unzipping";

    } else if (step === 2) {

    msg = "Uncompressing " + extras;

    } 
    else if (step === 3) {
    msg = "Reading OPS";
    } 
    else if (step === 4) {
    msg = "Post processing";
    alert(msg);
    } 
    else if (step === 5) {
    msg = "Finishing";
    alert('done!');
    } 
    else {
    msg = "Error!";
    }
    $('#something').html(msg);

    });

    }
    });
  });
```

pls can anyone tell me the mistake in the code above.

Comment: have you tried the suggestion given on the js-epub page to Base64 encode the XHTTP transfer?

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i got an error in js-unzip.js and it fails in step1 itself.

Comment: Sounds like you did not decode from Base64 before processing

Comment: i have used the base64.js from the link **https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64** but it is not decoding the data can u pls suggest me anyother links.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have tried the validate-function of js-epub?

```
 var vali = epub.validate();
```

Your console should now throw an exception if some values are "undefined";

By the way.. while checking the js-epub.js Code - there is a "new"-tag missing on line 15(inflate).... Maybe this solves your problem.

EDIT: IF you solve the problem it would be nice to share the answer.